# Why my output for this Multi threading program is unordered?

Tags: java, multithreading

```
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledFuture;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

public class ScheduledExecuterServicePractice {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("Started");
    
    NumberManager nm= new NumberManager();
    
    ExecutorService newFixedThreadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++) {
    newFixedThreadPool.submit(()-> 
    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().toString()+" "+nm.incrementCount()));
    }
    newFixedThreadPool.shutdown();
  }

}

class NumberManager{
  //int count =0;
  AtomicInteger count = new AtomicInteger();
  public int incrementCount() {
    
    return count.incrementAndGet();
    
  }
}
```

The output is

```
 Started
Thread[pool-2-thread-3,5,main] 1
Thread[pool-2-thread-4,5,main] 4
Thread[pool-2-thread-1,5,main] 3
Thread[pool-2-thread-5,5,main] 5
Thread[pool-2-thread-2,5,main] 2
Thread[pool-2-thread-6,5,main] 6
Thread[pool-2-thread-7,5,main] 8
Thread[pool-2-thread-8,5,main] 7
Thread[pool-2-thread-9,5,main] 9
Thread[pool-2-thread-10,5,main] 10
```

My question is how the value 4 is printed before 3. I have used atomic class. So only one thread can do the operation at on time.

I have printed the thread name and the count. So if the count is 0 and one thread comes and make it 1 so that should be displayed in the terminal right? then if another thread comes and executes then the value 2 will be printed ? But Here I don't understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is below code

```
ExecutorService newFixedThreadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
for(int i=0;i<10;i++) {
  newFixedThreadPool.submit(()-> 
  System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().toString()+" "+nm.incrementCount()));
}
```

The 10 threads are not guarantee to execute in order:

> `System.out.println` and `nm.incrementCount()` are not guaranteed in the same order

A more details explanation:

1. `Thread-1` invoke `nm.incrementCount()`,the value is 1
2. `Thread-2` invoke `nm.incrementCount()`,the value is 2
3. `Thread-2` print value of `nm.incrementCount()`,the output is 2
4. `Thread-1` print value of `nm.incrementCount()`,the output is 1

If you want to them to print in order,you can use `newFixedThreadPool` or `newSingleThreadExecutor()` instead

```
ExecutorService newFixedThreadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
//ExecutorService newFixedThreadPool = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
for(int i=0;i<10;i++) {
  newFixedThreadPool.submit(()-> 
  System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" "+nm.incrementCount()));
}
```

Comment: But I don't understand the 2nd line of my Output.

Comment: The value is 4 . So that means other threads changed the value to 2 then 3. And then this thread changed the value to 4. If other threads changed the value to 2,3 then how come they are not printed in the terminal first?

Comment: @UtkalkeshariSahu if you want to print thread name ,you need to use `Thread.currentThread().getName()`

Comment: @UtkalkeshariSahu Because the print order is not the same order when the value changed

Comment: Okay...But Why ?

Comment: @UtkalkeshariSahu just updated my answer and you can test it by yourself